# SAXNotRecognizedException when reading excel file using Apache POI

Tags: android, excel, xml, apache-poi, sax

I am trying to read an excel file using Apache POI library,the app is two button one to select the file and one to read it ,every time I instantiate a `Workbook` class I get the exception `SAXNotRecognizedException: http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler`

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.excelreader, PID: 2929
    java.lang.RuntimeException: http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.<init>(Locale.java:3397)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$XmlReaderSaxLoader.<init>(Locale.java:3087)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.getSaxLoader(Locale.java:3072)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1272)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1259)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
        at org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source:6)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:86)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.-$$Lambda$gobcPWQfEUc0tCYBAe7wHcxGUMU.init(Unknown Source:2)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:61)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:684)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:180)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:288)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:97)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:125)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.-$$Lambda$iuO6AyjZtGZgoUB0mS-ZEceWnhc.apply(Unknown Source:8)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:327)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:295)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:276)
        at com.example.excelreader.MainActivity.readExcelFile(MainActivity.kt:127)
        at com.example.excelreader.MainActivity.access$readExcelFile(MainActivity.kt:22)
        at com.example.excelreader.MainActivity$onCreate$2.onClick(MainActivity.kt:55)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14970)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29363)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
     Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler
        at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.setProperty(ExpatReader.java:168)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.<init>(Locale.java:3391)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$XmlReaderSaxLoader.<init>(Locale.java:3087) 
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.getSaxLoader(Locale.java:3072) 
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1272) 
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1259) 
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345) 
        at org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source:6) 
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:86) 
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.-$$Lambda$gobcPWQfEUc0tCYBAe7wHcxGUMU.init(Unknown Source:2) 
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:61) 
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:684) 
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:180) 
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:288) 
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:97) 
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:125) 
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.-$$Lambda$iuO6AyjZtGZgoUB0mS-ZEceWnhc.apply(Unknown Source:8) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:327) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:295) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:276) 
        at com.example.excelreader.MainActivity.readExcelFile(MainActivity.kt:127) 
        at com.example.excelreader.MainActivity.access$readExcelFile(MainActivity.kt:22) 
        at com.example.excelreader.MainActivity$onCreate$2.onClick(MainActivity.kt:55) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14970) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29363) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

here is my code:

```
package com.example.excelreader

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.util.Log.d
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory
import org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.InputStream

private const val DOCUMENT_PICKING_REQUEST=1000
const val TAG="te~st"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var  targetFile: File?=null

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if(requestCode==DOCUMENT_PICKING_REQUEST){
            if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                val path= data?.data
                if(path!=null){
                    targetFile=createFileFromURI(path)
                }
                Toast.makeText(this, "document selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, " no document selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)





        docPickButton.setOnClickListener {
            dispatchFilePickIntent()
        }

        readButton.setOnClickListener {
                readExcelFile()
            


          }

    }



    private fun dispatchFilePickIntent(){
        val intent= Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.type="*/*"
        startActivityForResult(intent, DOCUMENT_PICKING_REQUEST)
    }


    private fun createFileFromURI(source: Uri): File?{
        val inputStream=contentResolver.openInputStream(source)
        val file=createExcelFile()
        if(inputStream!=null && file!=null){
            val outputStream= FileOutputStream(file)
            var length=0
            while (length!= -1){
                length=inputStream.read()
                outputStream.write(length)
            }
            inputStream.close()
            outputStream.close()

        }
        return file
    }

    private fun readFromInputStream(inputStream:InputStream){
        val workbook= WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream)
        val sheet=workbook.getSheetAt(0)
        val row1=sheet.getRow(0)
        val iterator=row1.cellIterator()
        val cells= arrayListOf<Cell>()
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            val cell= iterator.next()
            cells.add(cell)
        }
        workbook.close()
        d(TAG, cells.toString())

    }


    private fun createDirectory(): File?{
        val directory= File(filesDir,"AppExcelFiles")
        return if(directory.exists()){
            directory
        }else{
            if(directory.mkdir()){
                directory
            }else{
                null
            }
        }
    }

    private fun createExcelFile(): File?{
        val directory=createDirectory()
        return if(directory!=null){
            val file= File(directory,"MyExcelFile.xlsx")
            file
        }else{
            null
        }
    }

    private fun readExcelFile(){
        val workbook= WorkbookFactory.create(targetFile)
        val sheet=workbook.getSheetAt(0)
        val row1=sheet.getRow(0)
        val iterator=row1.cellIterator()
        val cells= arrayListOf<Cell>()
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            val cell= iterator.next()
            cells.add(cell)
        }
        workbook.close()
        d(TAG, cells.toString())
    }

}
```

I guess that the problem is in the library XmlBeans , but I really can't figure out how to resolve that issue I tried changing the libraries version but the issue presists, any help would be very appreciated , thanks in advance

Comment: Have you solved it ? If yes then can you share solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Just include these dependencies in you build.gradle module:

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.17'
implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlbeans', name: 'xmlbeans', version: '3.1.0'
implementation 'javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0'
implementation 'com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.2.2'
```

Note: Don't go with the latest versions of the dependencies as they will generate errors.